# apache + proxy_fcgi_module + php-fpm: Large POST Payload empty

Tags: php, apache, post, payload

I am using apache 2.4.10 with proxy_fcgi in a combination with php-fpm (7.0.29) on my webserver.

```
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
  <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/www/xxx/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

When I send POST request with a large payload (> 1MB) I get the following line in Apache's error log

```
[Fri Apr 06 15:33:51 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24162:tid (32)Broken pipe: [client 84.63.x.x:37536] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (sending stdin), referer: -, request: /index.php, querystring: -
```

And in my PHP Code I got an empty payload when I read it from stdin:

```
$payload =file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Everything works with smaller payload. Any ideas what is wrong? I can't find any limit settings for proxy_fcgi...

Thanks for help!

Comment: I *think* the setting you're after is called `LimitRequestBody`. The other option could be ditching that crap server and using `nginx`, but that's just my opinion based on 9 years without (cr)Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now figured that the problem is with chunked Transfers (Transfer-Encoding: chunked) where no Content-Length Header is sent. mod_proxy_fcgi does not seem to support that correctly.

So the only possible solution seems to be using mod_php which runs directly within the apache process and not over FastCGI or switching to NginX...

Read this article for more information: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/apache-fastcgi-proxyfcgi-and-empty-post-bodies-chunked-transfer

Another Workaround seems to be forcing protocol HTTP/1.0 which does not support chunked transfers, forcing clients to send the whole data in one request. But this - in my case - breaks the TLS handshake in my git client.

As I am using my PHP script for proxying to a Git server, the solution for me is to raise the git client's http buffer until I am able to switch to NginX.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```